# SQL query: Identify duplicate values and also show the values in column that is not duplicated

Tags: sql, hadoop

I have data in hadoop that I'm analyzing. There are some duplicate entries where columns A,B are duplicated, and column C is distinct. What I want to do is identify only the A,B duplicated items, and then print out the distinct values of column C for each duplicated item.

Sample data:

```
row,  data, input_date, INPUT__FILE__NAME
  0, data1,   20180702,         LOCATION1
  1, data1,   20180702,         LOCATION2
  2, data1,   20180702,         LOCATION2

  3, data2,   20180702,         LOCATION1
  4, data2,   20180702,         LOCATION1
  5, data2,   20180702,         LOCATION2
  6, data2,   20180702,         LOCATION3
  7, data2,   20180702,         LOCATION3

  8, data3,   20180702,         LOCATION2

  9, data4,   20180702,         LOCATION3
```

(Note that `INPUT__FILE__NAME` is the metadata value in Hadoop of the file location where the data came from. In case that's relevant. But it can be treated just like another column in terms of SQL queries, as far as I know).

In this example I'd be using `data` and `input_date` to identify duplicates. And I want to be able to see the distinct `INPUT__FILE__NAME` of each of them.

Desired output (structure of the output can be changed if a different one makes sense -- I just need the distinct `INPUT_FILE_NAME` values):

```
    data, input_date, INPUT__FILE__NAME
   data1,   20180702,         LOCATION1
   data1,   20180702,         LOCATION2
   data2,   20180702,         LOCATION1
   data2,   20180702,         LOCATION2
   data2,   20180702,         LOCATION3
```

(So in the output, I **don't** need to see `data3` nor `data4` because they aren't duplicated.)

I've figured out that to identify the duplicates I can do the following:

```
SELECT data, input_date, count(DISTINCT INPUT__FILE__NAME)
FROM table
GROUP BY data, input_date
HAVING count(DISTINCT INPUT__FILE__NAME)>1;
```

However I haven't figured out a way to both identify the ones that have distinct count > 1 and then also print out those distinct values (because identifying the count>1 requires aggregating, but then printing the distinct values requires un-aggregating). Is it possible to do in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be inclined to use window functions:

```
select distinct data, input_date, input__file__name
from (select t.*,
             min(input__file__name) over (partition by data, input_date) as min_ifn,
             max(input__file__name) over (partition by data, input_date) as max_ifn
      from t
     ) t
where min_ifn <> max_ifn;
```

Comment: Does this work if a particular data-input_date pair has more than 2 distinct input_file_names though? it looks like you're only comparing two filenames (min and max) but one data-pair could have 3 or 4 input_file_names.

Comment: @andraiamatrix . . . Yes, it works for any number.  The minimum and maximum values will be different.

Comment: I tested it out and it looks like it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` :

```
select distinct t.data, t.input_date, t.INPUT__FILE__NAME
from table t
union all
select distinct t.data, t.input_date, t.INPUT__FILE__NAME
from table t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t1 
                  where t1.data = t.data and 
                        t1.input_date = t.input_date and
                        t1.INPUT__FILE__NAME <> t.INPUT__FILE__NAME
                 );
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 10:24 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'INPUT__FILE__NAME': SubQuery expression refers to both Parent and SubQuery expressions and is not a valid join condition.` specifically referring to the second last line `t1.INPUT__FILE__NAME <> t.INPUT__FILE__NAME`